# Can't make Guzzle accept a certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate, guzzle

I'm trying to have a server A communicate with a server B through HTTPS requests. Server B has a certificate that was issued to me by my employer, and connecting to it through both Safari and Chrome works without any issues.

However, when trying to send a request from A to B through Guzzle, I get the following error:

```
GuzzleHttp/Exception/RequestException with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: 
unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'
```

I've tried setting the cert file as a parameter ( `[verify => '/path/to/cert.pem']` ), but, first of all, I only had `.crt`, `.csr` and `.key` files; I tried making a `.pem` file through these instructions I found somewhere else:

> **(optional) Remove the password from the Private Key by following the steps listed below:**
>
> `openssl rsa -in server.key -out nopassword.key`
>
> Note: Enter the pass phrase of the Private Key.

> **Combine the private key, public certificate and any 3rd party intermediate certificate files:**
> `cat nopassword.key > server.pem`
> `cat server.crt >> server.pem`
> Note: Repeat this step as needed for third-party certificate chain files, bundles, etc:
> `cat intermediate.crt >> server.pem`

This didn't work – the error's the same. The request works with 'verify' set to false, but that's obviously not an option for production.

Certificates are not something I usually work with, so I'm having a lot of trouble just figuring out where the issue might lie, let alone fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**
I've also tried the solutions suggested in [Guzzle Curl Error 60 SSL unable to get local issuer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923604/guzzle-curl-error-60-ssl-unable-to-get-local-issuer) to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the only certificate I had configured on server B was the End User certificate.

I'm new to this, so my explanation will probably be flawed, but from my understanding End User certificates link back to a trusted Certificate Authority (CA) certificate, with zero or more intermediate certificates in-between. Browsers can figure out this certificate chain, and download the required certificates that are missing; cURL does not.

Therefore, the solution was configuring Server B with the missing certificates. How to do this is a whole different issue, so I won't go into it in this answer.